# Use a bazel query as a build shortcut?

Tags: bazel

Suppose you have this:

```
$ bazel query "filter('_image_publish$', attr(generator_function, go_server_v1, ...))" 
//helloworld/server:zurigo_server_image_publish
//bababot:bababot_server_image_publish
```

Is it possible to create rules or macros that let me do a single `bazel build` the builds all the targets above?

I'd like to do:

```
$ bazel build :all-servers
```

Which would implicitly build the ones from the output above. Is this possible?

Another way to put it, I'm looking for a Skylark alternative to doing a loop using bash on the output of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [`genquery()` rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genquery), which will write the query result targets into a file in `bazel-bin`.

The final command will look something like:

```
bazel build //package:my_genquery && cat bazel-bin/package/my_genquery | xargs bazel build
```

Comment: Can also be written:
`bazel build $(bazel query 'some_pattern')`

Comment: The `genquery` doesn't really work, because `genquery` rules are not allowed to contain wildcards like '`...`'.

Comment: Can also be written: `bazel query 'some_pattern' | bazel build $(cat)` if you want to keep things written in the order they happen in.